# wp7 equivalent of android's gridview

Tags: windows-phone-7, gridview, grid

What's wp7 equivalent of android's gridview?
I tried `Grid` but it is not clear to that it its suposed to work like android's `GridView`.

I want something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an equivalent for grid view is

> Wrappanel

You can use listbox embedded with wrappanel in itemtemplate to create control like gridview.

[For more information use this link](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth)